# Get Difference between 2 fields using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

Dears, I have a table like this:

```
day            Cases
29/04/2020      1123
28/04/2020      1090
27/04/2020      908
```

I want to get the difference between the number of cases for the last 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

The `LAG()` function produces the value of a previous row, according to the specified ordering criteria.

You can use it as shown below:

```
select t.*, cases - lag(cases) over(order by day) as diff from t
```

Comment: If the OP only cares about the last two days, put that in a `where` clause - no point in computing `lag()` over the entire table if it's really only needed over two rows.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the difference between the number of cases for the last 2 days

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select 
    max(case when rn = 1 then cases end) 
        - max(case when rn = 2 then cases end) case_diff
from (
    select cases, row_number() over(order by day desc) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn <= 2
```

In the subquery, `row_number()` ranks rows by descending `day`; then the outer query filters on the last two rows, and uses conditional expressions to get the difference between the last value and previous values of `cases`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select t.cases - tprev.cases
from t join
     t tprev
     on t.day = trunc(sysdate) and tprev.day = trunc(sysdate - 1);
```

You might be impressed with the performance if you have an index on `(day)`.